# Why can I not assign an address of a 1 star pointer to another without type casting?

Tags: c

I just wonder why ptr and p1 have the same type uint8_t but this code below warning that "assignment from incompatible type"

```
uint8_t *ptr=NULL;
uint8_t *p1=NULL;
ptr=&p1;
```

but when I type cast p1 from uint8_t to uint8_t that warning disappears

```
uint8_t *ptr =NULL;
uint8_t *p1=NULL;
ptr=(uint8_t*)&p1;
```

please help me I'm stuck on that issue for so long

Comment: Because `p1` have the type `uint8_t *`, the type of `&p1` will be `uint8_t **`. Think of the `&` operator as a *pointer-to* operator.

Comment: And using type-casting to silence the compiler is (almost) never the correct solution. In this case the types are still not equivalent, there's still a mismatch. You just tell the compiler to not care about it, leading to something bad.

Comment: ptr and p1 have the same type. But ptr and &p1 do not have the same type. &p1 has type uint8_t**

Comment: Further to what CGi03 and Some programmer dude are saying, applying the `&` operator to an object of any type yields a value with a type of pointer-to-that-other-type, and applying the `*` operator to a pointer to any type yields a value with that type.  Or, more simply, `&` adds a pointer level and `*` takes a level away.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared two variables, both of the same type: `uint8_t *`. This means they are both supposed to hold addresses of `uint8_t` objects. Since both variables are of the same type you can assign one to the other:

```c
ptr = p1;  // Valid
```

However, the `&` operator messes things up. `p1` is already a pointer, so it is supposed to hold the address of a `uint8_t`. But `&p1` creates a pointer to `p1`, i.e. a pointer-to-a-pointer to a `uint8_t`. `&p1` has type `uint8_t **` (notice the second `*`). It is supposed to hold the address of the address of a `uint8_t`.

therefore, there is a type mismatch. `ptr` holds a `uint8_t *`; `&p1` holds a `uint8_t **`.

Removing the ampersand will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a `uint8_t **` to a `uint8_t *`. Fix the issue by removing the ampersand:

```
uint8_t *ptr=NULL;
uint8_t *p1=NULL;
ptr=p1;
```